# Where to watch German world cup soccer games in Lisbon?

Tags: portugal, lisbon, world-cup

I will be visiting the beautiful town of Lisbon this weekend with a group of friends from Germany. Since the next German world cup game is pretty important we want to watch and support our team on Saturday (8 pm) against Sweden.

Unfortunately I don't speak Portuguese so I could not find a place online where this match will be shown. Does anybody know a place where we could watch the match **Sweden - Germany / Saturday 8 pm in Lisbon**? It does not have to be fancy but if possible it should be quite central and/or close to where we stay (city district **Baixa**).

I framed the question a bit broader because answers might be helpful for German visitors who will be visiting Lisbon at a later time during the world cup (and if Germany makes it to the Best of 16s of course).

Comment: I think every cafe/restaurant/bar which has a TV will have every World Cup game running on the screen.

Comment: Note the one hour time difference between Germany and Lisbon.

Comment: Thanks I did indeed not think of the time difference yet. Luckily that should be no problem for us!

Comment: Take a look at this group on FB: [Deutsche in Lissabon](https://www.facebook.com/groups/germansinlisbon).

Comment: Is there a way to [edit] this question so that it retains its usefulness after this World Cup is over?

Comment: Follow up question: Where can I watch anything but the World cup at any sports bar outside of the USA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Praça do Comércio" is a big square in Baixa, near the river. You'll have a fanzone there with a giant display screen of 90m2. There will be also food service and entertainments during break times. All games can be seen there (except if more than one game occurs at same time, of course).

Besides that, there are dozens of bars and restaurants in the zone. Most of them have good TVs where you can see the matches.

Good luck for the game :)

Comment: Some phrases that might help: "Posso ver o jogo da Copa do Mundo?" ("Can I watch the World Cup game?") "Posso ver o jogo entre a Alemanha e Suécia?" ("Can I watch the game between Germany and Sweden?") "Posso ver o jogo da Copa do Mundo entre a Alemanha e Suécia?" ("Can I watch the World Cup game between Germany and Sweden?")

Comment: That sounds awesome! Thanks for your answer I will suggest that to my friends! (Will leave the question open for today and then accept). Also thank you Robert I will keep those expressions in mind even though I have no clue how to pronounce them :D